# How to open Jetpack Navigation Fragment from Notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using Jetpack Navigation in my project following image describes my navigation. In my Application `Home Fragment` is my `NavHostFragment` and I'm using foreground service in `Fragment A`. When I navigate from `Home Fragment` to `Fragment A` and close the application or minimize then foreground service run with notification. When I pressed notification `Home fragment` open but I want `Fragment A` would be open and all back stack would be saved. I'm using `MainActivity` as a `PendingIntent` in notification where all my navigation fragments work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time, I found the solution. In this scenario, `Deeplinking` will be used. And change `PendingIntent` from `MainActivity` to your destination `FragmentA`.

[Source Help](https://github.com/orbitalsonic/Android-Jetpack-Navigation-Component-Example)

**nav_graph.xml**

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentA"
        android:label="Fragment A"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a">
       
        <action
            .../>
        
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:uri="www.example.com" />
    </fragment>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        ...>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**PendingIntent**

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
                .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
                .setDestination(R.id.fragment_a)
                .createPendingIntent()
```